# How to get the Wikidata ID (Q…) using just a label?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

Is there any way to get the Wikidata Q identifier of an entity using just the label as a string?

For example, "Java":

```
Q251
```

I want to search only the English labels.

Comment: So your input is "Java", and you want to get the Q-ID of all entities that have exactly "Java" as label? For example: [Q251](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q251), [Q3757](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3757), [Q2089134](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2089134), [Q61612399](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q61612399) etc.? Or should only English labels be considered?

Comment: @Stefan-broxIT-Solutions I want to get only the english version

Answer (score 2):

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?qid
WHERE {

  # make input string into a language-tagged string
  BIND( STRLANG("Java", "en") AS ?label ) .

  # search all items that have this languaged-tagged string as label
  ?item rdfs:label ?label .

  # extract the last path segment of the URI
  BIND(STRAFTER(STR(?item), STR(wd:)) AS ?qid) .

}
```

If you can append `@en` to the input string (`"Java"@en`), you can use:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?qid
WHERE {

  ?item rdfs:label "Java"@en .

  BIND(STRAFTER(STR(?item), STR(wd:)) AS ?qid) .

}
```

If you are fine with the URI (e.g., `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q251`) instead of the QID (e.g., `Q251`) as result, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item
WHERE {

  ?item rdfs:label "Java"@en .

}
```

If you want to ignore case, you can use [UCASE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-ucase) or [LCASE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase) in a `FILTER`.